# can someone give me precise instructions on how to install the compiz stereo3d plugin on ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, compiz, plugins

i looked at this link and tried all the instructions http://ddudek.pl/?p=39

first i tried this

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ddudek/stereo3d-stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install compiz-plugin-stereo3d
```

but there was no plugin available

then i tried the build for other distro instructions

couldnt download the code with this

```
 bzr branch lp:compiz-plugin-stereo3d/stable
```

i got

```
 bzr: ERROR: Already a branch: "stable".
```

dowloaded the source from here peice by piece:

```
 http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ddudek/compiz-plugin-stereo3d/trunk/files/1/
```

and followed these instructions

```
 cd [plugin]
 mkdir build
 cd build
 cmake ..
 make
 sudo make install

 Build dependencies are:

 compiz-dev compiz-plugins-main-dev intltool libgconf2-dev libglib2.0-dev 
 libtool libglu1-mesa-dev libjpeg62-dev libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev pkg-config 
 xsltproc libcairo2-dev libpango1.0-dev librsvg2-dev libsm-dev libdbus-1-dev 
 libdecoration0-dev libboost1.46-dev libboost-serialization1.46-dev cmake
```

but got ::

E: Package 'libboost1.46-dev' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'libboost-serialization1.46-dev' has no installation candidate

and the cmake line wasnt complete so of course it didnt run

so if some could help me with step by step instructions i would be very grateful

Edit

ok the cmake ..   worked but i got a bunch of error when i tried to make install

```
 [ 18%] Built target stereoscopicoutput_gsettings_schema
 [ 27%] Built target compiz_gsettings_compile_local
 [ 36%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/stereoscopicoutput.dir/src/stereoscopicoutput.cpp.o
 In file included from /home/w/Downloads/stereo-3d-plugin/src/stereoscopicoutput.cpp:14:0:
 /home/w/Downloads/stereo-3d-plugin/src/stereoscopicoutput.h:98:57: error: ‘GLFragment’ has not been declared
 /home/w/Downloads/stereo-3d-plugin/src/stereoscopicoutput.h:98:76: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘&’ token
 /home/w/Downloads/stereo-3d-plugin/src/stereoscopicoutput.h:108:53: error: ‘GLFragment’ has not been declared
 /home/w/Downloads/stereo-3d-plugin/src/stereoscopicoutput.h:108:72: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘&’ token
 /home/w/Downloads/stereo-3d-plugin/src/stereoscopicoutput.h:124:53: error: ‘GLFragment’ has not been declared
 /home/w/Downloads/stereo-3d-plugin/src/stereoscopicoutput.h:124:72: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘&’ token
 /home/w/Downloads/stereo-3d-plugin/src/stereoscopicoutput.h:128:9: error: ‘GLFragment’ does not name a type
 /home/w/Downloads/stereo-3d-plugin/src/stereoscopicoutput.h:130:9: error: ‘GLFragment’ does not name a type
 /home/w/Downloads/stereo-3d-plugin/src/stereoscopicoutput.h:295:21: error: ‘GLFragment’ has not been declared
 /home/w/Downloads/stereo-3d-plugin/src/stereoscopicoutput.h:295:40: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘&’ token
 /home/w/Downloads/stereo-3d-plugin/src/stereoscopicoutput.h:301:5: error: ‘GLFragment’ has not been declared
 /home/w/Downloads/stereo-3d-plugin/src/stereoscopicoutput.h:301:28: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘&’ token
 /home/w/Downloads/stereo-3d-plugin/src/stereoscopicoutput.cpp:375:5: error: ‘GLFragment’ has not been declared
 /home/w/Downloads/stereo-3d-plugin/src/stereoscopicoutput.cpp:375:24: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘&’ token
 /home/w/Downloads/stereo-3d-plugin/src/stereoscopicoutput.cpp: In member function ‘bool StereoscopicOutputWindow::glDraw(const GLMatrix&, int)’:
 /home/w/Downloads/stereo-3d-plugin/src/stereoscopicoutput.cpp:381:5: error: ‘mask’ was not declared in this scope
 /home/w/Downloads/stereo-3d-plugin/src/stereoscopicoutput.cpp:390:43: error: ‘fragment’ was not declared in this scope
 /home/w/Downloads/stereo-3d-plugin/src/stereoscopicoutput.cpp:390:53: error: ‘region’ was not declared in this scope
 /home/w/Downloads/stereo-3d-plugin/src/stereoscopicoutput.cpp: In member function ‘void StereoscopicOutputWindow::glDrawGeometry()’:
 /home/w/Downloads/stereo-3d-plugin/src/stereoscopicoutput.cpp:476:18: error: ‘class GLWindow’ has no member named ‘glDrawGeometry’
 /home/w/Downloads/stereo-3d-plugin/src/stereoscopicoutput.cpp: At global scope:
 /home/w/Downloads/stereo-3d-plugin/src/stereoscopicoutput.cpp:481:5: error: ‘GLFragment’ has not been declared
 /home/w/Downloads/stereo-3d-plugin/src/stereoscopicoutput.cpp:481:24: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘&’ token
 /home/w/Downloads/stereo-3d-plugin/src/stereoscopicoutput.cpp: In member function ‘void StereoscopicOutputWindow::glDrawTexture(GLTexture*, int)’:
 /home/w/Downloads/stereo-3d-plugin/src/stereoscopicoutput.cpp:484:5: error: ‘GLFragment’ has not been declared
 /home/w/Downloads/stereo-3d-plugin/src/stereoscopicoutput.cpp:484:24: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘fa’
 /home/w/Downloads/stereo-3d-plugin/src/stereoscopicoutput.cpp:494:76: error: ‘fa’ was not declared in this scope
 /home/w/Downloads/stereo-3d-plugin/src/stereoscopicoutput.cpp:510:39: error: ‘fa’ was not declared in this scope
 /home/w/Downloads/stereo-3d-plugin/src/stereoscopicoutput.cpp:510:43: error: ‘mask’ was not declared in this scope
 At global scope:
 cc1plus: warning: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-unused-private-field" [enabled by default]
 make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/stereoscopicoutput.dir/src/stereoscopicoutput.cpp.o] Error 1
 make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/stereoscopicoutput.dir/all] Error 2
 make: *** [all] Error 2
 root@w-VirtualBox:/home/w/Downloads/stereo-3d-plugin/build#
```

does anyone have any advice from here i layed out my folder the same way as at this link http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ddudek/compiz-plugin-stereo3d/trunk/files/1/ with those files at that link

Comment: The PPA only has packages for 11.10 and 12.04. Raring has `libboost1.49-dev`, not 1.46; same with `libboost-serialization1.49`.

Comment: Apparently, there is the `cmake ..` command according to [this](http://qt-project.org/quarterly/view/using_cmake_to_build_qt_projects). It also explains the reason for the 'build' folder. In short, it should work, just make sure you've installed cmake and all of the dependencies.

Comment: @mikewhatever pls see latest edits